# Don't create netcoreapp fodler in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, .net-core-3.1

When I create a file in Vs 2019 in bin/Debug folder it automaticly creates a netcoreapp3.1 folder and when I create a file without it automaticly puts there insted fo putting the bin/Debug folder.
So how can I disable creating this netcoreapp3.1 folder?

Comment: Why is this  a problem?  `instead of putting the bin/Debug folder` that's not instead-of. That's *exactly* where each target's compiled output is stored. This isnt' even about Visual Studio. A .NET Core application can target multiple runtimes. The compiled output for each runtime is placed in a runtime-specific folder.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? Why do you expect the output to be stored in a *different* folder? Why not adjust your tooling to read data from the correct folder? If you want to deploy the binaries you should *publish* them, not just compile them, especially if you want to create a single file executable

Comment: I got my answer from "Drew Noakes".

Comment: It's the same thing I posted. Why do you consider this to be a problem?

Comment: Well the actual answer is to put     <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath> in your projectfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`netcoreapp3.1` is the target framework for your project. That folder is only added to the output path when the project targets more than one target framework.

In your project file is probably a property like this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;somethingelse</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Your folder structure will look like:

```
bin
  netcoreapp3.1
    Debug
    Release
  somethingelse
    Debug
    Release
```

If you specify multiple platforms, then you'll see a level added for them too (e.g. `x86`, `AnyCPU`, `x64`, etc...).

When a project specifies multiple target frameworks, then building the project will build for each of those targets on *every build*. The output for each target will be slightly different.

It's important then that they end up in different folders, otherwise they'd overwrite each other and likely be incorrect.